# Realm: creating a new Role and adding a User to it fails

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to wrap my head around object-level access control permissions with Realm Cloud (using query-based sync). What I want, is that one object (say, a Task in my example below), can be viewed by a set of multiple users.

So, I create the task, create a role for it with the name `"task:\(task.taskId)"`, add the current user to that role, create a new permission for that role, and finally add it to the task.

```swift
let task = Task()
task.name = "A task!"

try? realm.write {
  realm.add(task)

  let taskRole = realm.create(PermissionRole.self, value: ["task:\(task.taskId)"])
  let permissionUser = realm.object(ofType: PermissionUser.self, forPrimaryKey: SyncUser.current!.identity!)!
  taskRole.users.append(permissionUser)

  let permission = task.permissions.findOrCreate(forRole: taskRole)
  permission.canRead = true
  permission.canUpdate = true
  permission.canDelete = true
}
```

The idea being that at a later point another user can be added to the same role, with having access to the Task, and nobody else.

Almost everything is working, except that the user is not actually being added to the role. When I look in Realm Studio, I can see that the task is created, the role is created, the permission is created and it's added to the task, but the role has no users at all.

What am I doing wrong? And are there better examples or docs? I find the official docs to be very sparse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering about how you have permissions set up. Are you sure you have permission to read that PermissionUser, and modify that PermissionRole?

Comment: Well I am able to create the PermissionRole. The new entry is added. But.. it has no users attached to it. Basically everything except appending the user to the role works.

Comment: what version of Realm?

Comment: Version 3.14.1.